# How can I pass multiple attributes to onChange handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<select>` form element with a list of items obtained from props and mapped as options. Each option has a Route value (option key) and a Description value (option display).

The select element has an onChange handler. I have only been able to pass one of the option attributes (`value`) based on the item selected. When I set the state, the value of `number` is undefined.

I've seen similar questions, but they are using older syntax.

How can I pass both the Route value and Description value based on the item selected?

```
import React from 'react';

class RouteSelect extends React.Component {
    state = {
        selectedRoute: {
            name: '',
            number: ''
        }
    }

    setSelectedRoute(route, e) {
        this.setState({
            selectedRoute: {
                name: e.target.value,
                number: route
            }
        });

        //console.log(this.state.selectedRoute);
    }

    render() {
        let routes = this.props.state.routes;
        let routeOptions = routes.map((route) =>
            <option key={route.Route._text}>{route.Description._text}</option>
        );

        return (
            <>
                <select
                    value={this.state.selectedRoute.Description}
                    onChange={(e) => this.setSelectedRoute(routes.Route, e)} >
                    {routeOptions}
                </select>
                { console.log(this.state) }
            </>
        );
    }
};

export default RouteSelect;
```

** UPDATE **

I updated my code based on Oliver's suggestion, and added the `useState` hook in the `onChange` handler. I'm still unable to get the route number. I currently have it set to `routes` which is returning the entire array of routes, as expected. I only added `routes` as a value to show that setting the state in this manner works. How can I set the route number based on the selected route?

RouteSelect.js

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';

const RouteSelect = props => {

    const { routes } = props;

    //console.log(routes);

    const [selectedRoute, setSelectedRoute] = useState({
        name: '',
        number: ''
    });

    const routeOptions = routes.map(route =>
        <option key={route.Route._text}>{route.Description._text}</option>
    );

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <select onChange={event =>       
                setSelectedRoute({
                    name: event.target.value,
                    number: routes
                })}
            >
                {routeOptions}
            </select>
            {console.log(selectedRoute)}
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default RouteSelect;
```

RouteForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import RouteSelect from './RouteSelect';

const parser = require('xml-js');

class RouteForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        routes: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let routeList = [];
        fetch("https://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/Routes")
            .then(response => { 
                return response.text();
            }).then(response => {
                //console.log(JSON.parse(parser.xml2json(response, {compact: true, spaces: 4})))
                return JSON.parse(parser.xml2json(response, {compact: true, spaces: 4}));
            }).then(response => {
                const res = response.ArrayOfNexTripRoute.NexTripRoute;
                routeList = res.map((route) => {
                    return route
                });
                this.setState({
                    routes: routeList
                });

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.state.routes && <RouteSelect routes={this.state.routes} />  
        );
    }
};

export default RouteForm;
```

Comment: Why pass route to setSelectedRoute? You have `this.props.state.routes.Route` available in that function so you can just do: `onChange={this.setSelectedRoute}`. You can also define `setSelectedRoute` as an arrow function so you don't get binding issues.

Comment: I believe your approach is not the best but you can try to bind the function by `myFunction.bind(null, argument1, argument2)`

Comment: @HMR can you please add this in an answer? If it works I’d like to give you credit.

Answer (score 3):

Newest syntax could look something like this:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';

const RouteSelect = props => {
    const { routes } = props;
    const [selectedRoute, setSelectedRoute] = useState({ name: '', number: '' });

    const handleChange = route => event => {
        setSelectedRoute({ name: event.target.value, number: route });
    };

    const routeOptions = routes.map(route => <option key={route.Route._text}>{route.Description._text}</option>);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <select value={selectedRoute.Description} onChange={handleChange(routes.Route)}>
                {routeOptions}
            </select>
            {console.log(selectedRoute)}
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default RouteSelect;
```

I think it's important to note that you should never use `this.props.state.x` as that is confusing. Data should either be handled by state (local state or redux store) or passed in above via props.

Comment: Since you use hooks maybe try useState for handleChange \

Comment: @Oliver, can you please check my question again? I added an UPDATE section where I used your suggestion. I am still unable to access the route number, but maybe you will know what I am doing wrong? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: where is the actual route data? It appears that you're actually trying to do even more than you posted here and it's hard to help by guessing at what's going on.

Comment: @Oliver I updated my question to include the component that gets the data.

Comment: I edited my answer slightly - the `<select value={selectedRoute.Description}` is fixed, you probably need to fix what's being passed into the onChange function because I presume `routes.Route` is not what you mean to pass into that funciton, you probably want `routes.description` or `routes.Route.description`

Answer (score 2):

Since route is in this.props.state (maybe rename it to make it less confusing) you don't need to pass it:

```
class RouteSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedRoute: {
      name: '',
      number: '',
    },
  };
  //make it an arrow function to auto bind this
  setSelectedRoute = e =>
    this.setState({
      selectedRoute: {
        name: e.target.value,
        number: this.props.state.routes.Route,
      },
    });

  render() {
    let routes = this.props.state.routes;
    let routeOptions = routes.map(route => (
      <option key={route.Route._text}>
        {route.Description._text}
      </option>
    ));

    return (
      <>
        <select
          value={this.state.selectedRoute.Description}
          onChange={this.setSelectedRoute}
        >
          {routeOptions}
        </select>
        {console.log(this.state)}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default RouteSelect;
```

Comment: would you please take a look at the UPDATE in my question? Thanks so much for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe easiest solution would be just to try to fetch required values from your options array based on selected value.

So in your onChange handler search for corresponding route by selected value.

Comment: Can you please provide a specific code example answer so I can check your idea?